# Postgres - sharing data sets between applications

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two web applications, admin one and public one. While both have a fair amount of separate data, a certain part, let's call them items, are used in both. To be more exact, items are created and edited in admin application, and then displayed in public application.

Since both are using PostgreSQL as database backend, I figured they could be joined in database level - I would create views in public database that get data over dblink to admin database.

Is this a good solution, given following constraints?

- There are quite many items,
- Public application will do extensive searching over the data set,
- It's ok for the data to be little bit stale on public side,
- Currently the applications use the same physical database server, but might split in future;

If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than the data being in separate databases, put everything into a single database, and then use [schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html) and [access permissions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/user-manag.html) to separate things out.

Specifically:

- The public and admin sites should connect using different "login roles" (users).
- Tables only used by the admin site could be in an `admin` schema, and the public user would not have `USAGE` granted for that schema.
- Other sections of data could be put into named schemas, some of which would be fully accessible by both sites, some of which would have a mixture. (You can use `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA` and [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) if you divide your schemas up well.)
- Tables to which public should have some read-only access could, as you say, be referenced in views. The public user can be `GRANT`ed access to these views rather than the underlying tables. Views can reference tables in another schema, or even across multiple schemas, if that helps you manage things.
- Alternatively, read-only access to a whole table can be granted by simply not giving the public user `INSERT` and `UPDATE` privileges on that table.

You may even find it useful to think of public and admin not as separate applications, but as different front-end interfaces to the same application - there may be code that should be shared between them rather than copied-and-pasted, for instance.

Comment: Same database and different schemas might be a solution - I'll look into it. However, as far as split applications go, that was a conscious decision on my side, to allow slightly different 'business rules' and independent development and scaling of them. Code re-use can be handled through shared libraries :)

Comment: @TomsMikoss Ah, I see, shared libraries make sense. The main consideration in separating databases is writes: read-only operations can be scaled (fairly) easily using replication (leaving the admin site connected to the single master copy), but things the public site needs to write to (e.g. logs) might be worth separating out.

Comment: @TomsMikoss The other thing to consider with separate DBs is that you can't commit an atomic transaction across more than one DB without jumping through lots of hoops with two-phase commit (prepared transactions). This means you may need a bunch more application logic to synchronize certain changes and make sure things don't half-applied than you would if you used a single DB with multiple schemas.

Comment: @TomsMikoss BTW, PostgreSQL 9.3 will have writeable foreign data wrappers for PostgreSQL tables, so you can create link tables.

Answer (score 0):

Let public access the `admin` db directly and control the privileges with roles.

[Database Roles](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/user-manag.html)